# GWCODE CATEGORIES - Channel entries

Tags: categories

I am trying to display a series of entries ordered by subcategories using a category segment

```
{exp:gwcode_categories cat_id="{last_segment_category_id}" last_only="yes" style="linear"}
<h2>{cat_name}</h2>
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="yes" channel="work" status="not Closed" sort="asc" category="{cat_id}"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

But I can only get the cat_names to appear, I cannot get the entries to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used this addon, but looks like a [parsing order](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html) issue. Set the parameter [parse](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/plugins.html) to "inward".

```
{exp:gwcode_categories cat_id="{last_segment_category_id}" last_only="yes" style="linear" parse="inward"}
    <h2>{cat_name}</h2>
    {exp:channel:entries dynamic="yes" channel="work" status="not Closed" sort="asc" category="{cat_id}"}
        {title}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```